# Match to end of string

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following string (`joe` could be `sally` or `susan` too):

`test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe`.

I want to remove the beginning of the string up to `"CREATED-BY"` to be left with `joe`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Show your attempts and expected output.

Comment: Got to here: `/\CREATED-BY\b\W/`, which highlights the CREATED-BY part.

Comment: `/(?<=CREATED-BY).+$/`

Comment: I highly suggest using Rubular, an online tool for regular expressions. It also lets you choose the version of Ruby, and gives you a cheat sheet.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to get parse out the beginning of the phrase`? I'm not a God to read your mind.

Comment: If the string is 'test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe_smith', what do you want returned?

Comment: If you remove up to `"CREATED-BY"`, you will be left with `"-joe"`, not `"joe"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
string = 'test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe'
string.match(/CREATED-BY-(\S+)\z/)[1]
#=> "joe"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe".partition("CREATED-BY-").last # => "joe"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `split` instead of a regex?

```
> 'test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe'.split('CREATED-BY-').last
=> "joe"
```

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because I see I misread the question. I'll delete this one as well, once you've seen it. You may want to delete your comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two more ways:

```
s = "test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe"

s[/CREATED-BY-\K.+/]
  #=> "joe"
```

and:

```
s[s.rindex('CREATED-BY-')+'CREATED-BY-'.size..-1]
  #=> "joe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [String's `[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method, which can take a regular expression and return a specific capture:

```
str = 'test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe'
str[/CREATED-BY-(\S+)/, 1]
# => "joe"
```

`(\S+)` is the magic part, which tells the Regular Expression engine to return everything that's not a space. If the string extends beyond `joe`, like

```
test. 456. CREATED-BY-joe,MODIFIED-BY-fred
```

there'd be a problem, but that'd be an easy fix.